# Extracting the first value from a table column containing nested list

Tags: r

Working in RStudio, I am performing an api to openweathermap.
The json returned is converted to a dataframe.

The code that I am using to get the JSON is:

```
text2 <- GET('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=43.15&lon=-89.29&dt=1621425600&appid=yourappidhere')
jsonOpenWeather <- fromJSON(rawToChar(text2$content))
```

The returned column jsonOpenWeather$weather is the column containing lists. Each list has four variables ('id', 'main', 'description', 'icon') and oberservations ranging from 1 to 4.

I would like to extract the first observation from the second variable and have this value replace its originating list.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the 'weather' column of the object, extract the `main` column and get the first observation

```
jsonOpenWeather2 <- sapply(jsonOpenWeather$weather, function(x) x$main[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response akrun. I tried your code but unfortunately, I returned and List of 0. I did come to a solution, although it wasn't elegant. I did the following:  
`b="rain"`
`for(i in 1:length(test$dt))`
`{`
`  a= tester[[i]][2][[1]][1]`
`  b = rbind(b, a)`
`}`
`main <- data.frame(b)`
`main <- main[-1,]`
`test$weather <- main`

Comment: @S.Hyland your `GET` code is not rperoducible, so this is based on just the descrption

Comment: @S.Hyland your code shows `test` and `tester` are they the same